# npm install [package] removing packages

Tags: npm, npm-install

npm install [package] command is removing other packages and I have to run 'npm install' command to reinstall them which is a tedious task.

All packages are recorded in the package.json and package-lock.json files.

If I npm install [package b], it will install package b but remove package a.
This occurs vice versa with other packages.

I always have to run 'npm install' to return all removed packages so that now 'packages a and b' exist in the node_modules as intended.

Is this normal procedure for adding packages? Or is there a way I can avoid using 'npm intall' after adding a new package?

Comment: Are you *sure* packages A and B are both included in package.json? Do you have `save=false` in an .npmrc?

Comment: Yes. 'package a' exists in package-lock.json until 'package b' is installed (and removes 'package a' from the node_modules and package-lock.json). However 'package a' is still referenced in package.json (both are dependencies) even after this. I believe this is why they all reinstall after the npm install

Comment: If you remove package-lock.json and run `npm install`, do they both stay?

Comment: Yes. All packages remain after deleting package-lock.json then npm install

Comment: Just had the same problem, Why would this happen?

Comment: Have this issue, too. Removing package-lock.json did the trick...

Answer (score 1):

There was a pruning bug in NPM 5.7 which was resolved not long after this question was posted.

https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/17379

It's apparently resolved as of 5.7.1.