# npm install [package] is removing packages

Tags: npm, npm-install

After cloning a repo, I run `npm ci` and get back
`added 2425 packages in 413.413s`

Add a new package, `npm install js-file-download`

```
+ js-file-download@0.4.12
added 1 package from 1 contributor, removed 186 packages and audited 2240 packages in 33.76s
```

package.json has one line added
[image]

but package-lock.json has many lines removed (including the @dealertrack/dms-shell-client-react package that is a top level dependency of my project)
[image]

I've confirmed that after the `npm ci` there's an `@dealertrack` folder in `node_module` that gets removed by the `npm install <package>`.

running `npm install`, re-adds the packages removed

> added 186 packages from 186 contributors and audited 2426 packages in
> 46.594s

However, it also changes the resolution of numerous packages in package-lock.json from the public `registry.npmjs.org` to our company's npm repo in artifactory.

According to [this question & answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48841884/npm-install-package-removing-packages), there was a pruning bug in npm 5.7 that was fixed in 5.7.1.  But I'm seeing this in both 6.9.0 (as installed with node 10.16.0 by nvm-windows) and 6.14.11.

I ran across another similar question (that I can't find now) showing packages removed by `npm install <package>` and added back by `npm install`.  Lastly [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64109561/npm-removing-dependencies-on-each-install) from 5 months ago seems to imply the npm is broken and the fix is to use yarn.

I do not see this same removing packages behavior running npm 7.6.3 (but that also updates package-lock.json to v2, which means I'd need to get all my collaborators to update.)

So is npm 6.x.x broken?  Or is there a version that works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran across this npm bug report [npm ci behaves incorrectly with some version numbers](https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/1353)
which had a link to the archived post
[npm prune –production (after npm ci only) erroneously uninstalls regular dependency](https://npm.community/t/npm-prune-production-after-npm-ci-only-erroneously-uninstalls-regular-dependency/5055)

So I started looking at how the @dealertrack package was specified.

I changed

```
"@dealertrack/dms-shell-client-react": "0.0.29-41-c0de2"
```

to

```
"@dealertrack/dms-shell-client-react": "^0.0.29-41"
```

And `npm ci` completed successfully.

Then I installed the `js-file-download` package, and only that 1 package was added, nothing removed.

```
+ js-file-download@0.4.12
added 1 package from 1 contributor and audited 2426 packages in 49.746s
```

package-lock.json had the following changes...

```
     "@dealertrack/dms-shell-client-react": {
-      "version": "0.0.29-41-c0de2",
+      "version": "0.0.29-41c0de2",
```

and

```
+    "js-file-download": {
+      "version": "0.4.12",
+      "resolved": "https://artifactory.coxautoinc.com/artifactory/api/npm/cai-npm/js-file-download/-/js-file-download-0.4.12.tgz",
+      "integrity": "sha1-EMcO82JVmlsjzb3DvW85nD2R2CE="
+    },
```

In addition, another `npm ci` completed successfully.

Now I'm nowhere close to being a node/npm expert...but it seems to me that `0.0.29-41-c0de2` isn't a valid version according to the Semantic Versioning rules.  But that is actually what's in our internal artifactory repo.  No idea why `npm ci` or `npm install` don't care, but apparently `npm prune` does.

So, in short...I guess npm 6 is broken...
But maybe this work-a-round will help somebody.

I've also reached out to our internal team that maintains the package in question to find out why they never released 0.0.29 :)